# Windows store apps 8.1 Mediaelement sample File not found exception

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, media

using the media playback sample for windows store apps 8.1 and visual studio 2013:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/basic-media-playback-003619be

i tried opening any audio or video file but every time the application crashes with a file not found exception at line:

```
        Scenario1MediaElement.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
```

and when i debugging i always find file.ContentType returning an empty string .

any one knows what's going on?!

Answer (score 0):

Updating the latest version of windows 8.1 solved this issue on my side!

but the video will run only on the local machine .

to get required updates straight forward, download the latest version of media player from official Microsoft website.